# Drawing of matching boxes in LaTeX

Tags: boxes, line-spacing

I want to draw a split with diffrent blocks inside each one there is the block index.

Since I am new to LaTeX, I tried to use

```
\fbox{$b_{0}$}\fbox{$b_{1}$}\fbox{$b_{2}$}%
\fbox{$..........................$}%
\fbox{$b_{S.t -1}$}\fbox{$b_{s.t}$}
```

However, this gives boxes of different sizes. Is there any other suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

EDITED to use LaTeX101 construct `\framebox{}`, instead of `\fbox{\makebox{}}` (D'oh!).

[image]

Use a `\framebox` instead of an `\fbox`, since it allows a box width to be specified.  In this example, I choose 1 inch size and center alignment within the box.  That is changed for the last example to left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\fxbox[1]{\framebox[1in][c]{#1}}
\parskip 1em\parindent 0in
\begin{document}
ORIGINAL:\\
\fbox{$b_{0}$}\fbox{$b_{1}$}\fbox{$b_{2}$}\fbox{$........................$%
  }\fbox{$b_{S.t -1}$}\fbox{$b_{s.t}$} 

UNIFORM WIDTH (center alignment):\\
\fxbox{$b_{0}$}\fxbox{$b_{1}$}\fxbox{$b_{2}$}\fxbox{$........................$%
  }\fxbox{$b_{S.t -1}$}\fxbox{$b_{s.t}$} 

\renewcommand\fxbox[1]{\framebox[1in][l]{\strut#1}}

UNIFORM WIDTH \& HEIGHT (left alignment):\\
\fxbox{$b_{0}$}\fxbox{$b_{1}$}\fxbox{$b_{2}$}\fxbox{$........................$%
  }\fxbox{$b_{S.t -1}$}\fxbox{$b_{s.t}$} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll also note in the middle image that the vertical height of the boxes are a different, because of the height/depth of the content.  If you would like those the same, you could define `\fxbox` as in the third example

```
\newcommand\fxbox[1]{\framebox[1in][l]{\strut#1}}
```

The `\strut` will extend the vertical box to the full line-height extent.

Comment: I don't want the boxes to have any space between them, to give an impression of a split divided to boxes

Comment: `\fbox{\makebox` is `\framebox`

Comment: @rima101 the space is the word-space between the boxes, if you don't put a space between the boxes you will get no space like `aa` instead of `a a` `\fbox` itself adds no margin outside the frame.

Comment: I understand now .

Comment: What is `LaTeX101` ?

Comment: @Daniel *anything*101 is an idiomatic expression in American English signifying the first course in a college sequence, or more generally the most elementary concept.  Seeing as `\framebox` is on p.98 of Lamport's text, it is somewhat embarrassing to not recall it in my sleep.

Comment: Ah, learned something new :-)

Comment: @Daniel I suppose I should either not use idioms for an international audience or clarify.  To that end, "D'oh" is the expression used by American TV animated character Homer Simpson, upon realizing that he made an elementary mistake. (see edit)

Answer (score 4):

A TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={
            draw,minimum width=1in,
            text height=1.75ex,
            text depth=0.5ex,
        },
        node distance=-\pgflinewidth,
    ]
        \node (b 0) {$b_0$};
        \node (b 1) [right=of b 0] {$b_1$};
        \node (b 2) [right=of b 1] {$b_2$};
        \node (dots) [right=of b 2] {.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.\,.};
        \node (b St-1) [right=of dots] {$b_{S.t -1}$};
        \node (b St) [right=of b St-1] {$b_{S.t}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: some boxes]

I used the `every node` style to let all nodes in the picture have the same width and hight, and draw the border. You can delete the lines with `text depth` and `text height` to let the nodes have their natural height. The `node distance` is set to the line width of the border, so between the nodes it looks like they share the line.

Comment: The text in the nodes are on different baselines (evident for the `dots` node, but the others might also differ). I'd suggest adding something like `text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex` to the node style to amend this. (This is kind of like adding a strut of height `1.5ex` and depth `0.25ex` to every text node.) [See further _TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 2.1_, $5.1 (pp 60-62)].

Comment: @Johan_E: That’s a good idea, didn’t thought about that … :-)

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions.

(1) The width is set to the widest entry, but an optional argument is provided for modifying it by addition. A second optional argument (in parentheses) is the inner alignment, default center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\rimatightboxes}{ O{0pt} D(){c} m }
 {
  \rima_tightboxes:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_rima_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_rima_boxes_seq
\dim_new:N \l_rima_width_dim
\box_new:N \l_rima_entry_box

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rima_tightboxes:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_rima_input_seq { , } { #3 }
  \dim_zero:N \l_rima_width_dim
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_rima_input_seq
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnF { ##1 } { \dots }
     {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_rima_entry_box { $##1$ }
      \dim_set:Nn \l_rima_width_dim
       { \dim_max:nn { \l_rima_width_dim } { \box_wd:N \l_rima_entry_box } }
     }
   }
  \dim_add:Nn \l_rima_width_dim { (#1 + \fboxsep) * 2}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_rima_boxes_seq \l_rima_input_seq
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \dots }
     {
      \exp_not:n { \framebox[\l_rima_width_dim][#2] { \strut\dotfill } }
     }
     {
      \exp_not:n { \framebox[\l_rima_width_dim][#2] { \strut$##1$ } }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_rima_boxes_seq { \kern-\fboxrule }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\rimatightboxes{b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\bigskip

\rimatightboxes(l){b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\bigskip

\rimatightboxes[3pt]{b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\bigskip

\rimatightboxes[3pt](r){b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(2) The width is set via an optional argument (default 0.5in). A second optional argument (in parentheses) is the inner alignment, default center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\rimaboxes}{ O{0.5in} D(){c} m }
 {
  \rima_boxes:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_rima_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_rima_boxes_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rima_boxes:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_rima_input_seq { , } { #3 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_rima_boxes_seq \l_rima_input_seq
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \dots }
     {
      \exp_not:n { \framebox[#1][#2] { \strut\dotfill } }
     }
     {
      \exp_not:n { \framebox[#1][#2] { \strut$##1$ } }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_rima_boxes_seq { \kern-\fboxrule }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\rimaboxes{b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\bigskip

\rimaboxes(l){b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\bigskip

\rimaboxes[.3in]{b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\bigskip

\rimaboxes[.3in](r){b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{st-1},b_{st}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the last two examples don't really fit.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*6{>{\centering$}X<{$}|}}
\hline
b_0&b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_{s.t-1}&b_{s.t}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```